# paintComponent is executing twice

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

This is bothering me, my code works and runs but when I went to run it, it seems to be looping my for loops twice, can anyone help me with my logic? Thanks...

```
package pkgcirc;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;

/*
* Notes:
* Draw 20 circles
* radius/location (x/y/r) all random
* if (circle) is between radii pt (step thru loop) of all values, if its within ,
*  draw it cyan if it overlaps, else black
*  
*/
public class Main extends JPanel {
    int[] radius = new int [3];
    int[] xArray = new int [3];
    int[] yArray = new int [3];

    public Main()
    {       
        Random g = new Random();
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension(300, 200));
        for(int i = 0; i < radius.length; i++)
        {
            radius[i] = g.nextInt(50)+1;
            xArray[i] = g.nextInt(250)+1;
            yArray[i] = g.nextInt(150)+1;
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
    {
        super.paintComponent(page);
        for(int i = 0; i < radius.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < radius.length; j++)
            {
                int xpoint1 = xArray[i]+radius[i];
                int ypoint1 = yArray[i]+radius[i];
                int xpoint2 = xArray[j]+radius[j];
                int ypoint2 = yArray[j]+radius[j];
                int radius1 = radius[i];
                int radius2 = radius[j];
                boolean Collide = circlesCollide(xpoint1, ypoint1, radius1, radius2, xpoint2, ypoint2);

                if (i != j && Collide == false)
                {
                    page.setColor(Color.cyan);
                    page.fillOval(xArray[i] ,yArray[i], radius[i], radius[i]);
                    System.out.println("false");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("true");
                    page.setColor(Color.black);
                    page.drawOval(xArray[j] ,yArray[j], radius[j], radius[j]);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("BREAK");    
        }
    }

    public boolean circlesCollide(double x1, double y1, double r1, double x2, double y2, double r2){
        return (distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) <= (r1 + r2));
    }

    public double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        return Math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)));
    }       

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Circles");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add (new Main());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `setPreferredSize()` and `pack()` will cause `paintComponent()` to be called twice because the display needs to be redrawn for each call.

Try removing `pack()` and move set size to the bottom, like this:-

```
public Main() {
    Random g = new Random();

    //setPreferredSize(...); // commented this line

    for (int i = 0; i < radius.length; i++) {
        radius[i] = g.nextInt(50) + 1;
        xArray[i] = g.nextInt(250) + 1;
        yArray[i] = g.nextInt(150) + 1;
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
        ...
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circles");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setSize(300, 200); // added this line

    frame.getContentPane().add(new Main());

    // frame.pack(); // commented this line

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

This should work properly now.

Comment: Oh cripes :) remind me in 21 hours to come back and upvote. :)

Comment: Hmm, it is still drawing it twice, man I'm pulling my hair out :(

Comment: @novar: It's not invoking your paintComponent() twice. Comment all your code in paintComponent() and put a sysout, and you will see that it is being called just one time. I know it, because I had your code running here. :)

Comment: @sarnold: Don't worry about it. I have that 30-vote-limit problem a few times myself too. :)

Comment: Is there something wrong with my loops, I keep going through them and trying different things, but it seems to print out the same lines twice, true
true
false
BREAK
true
false
BREAK
true
BREAK

REPEAT STARTS HERE



true
true
false
BREAK
true
false
BREAK
true
BREAK

Comment: See how its the same output twice? >:\

Comment: Hmm, is my page.setColor(Color.cyan);
causing paintcomponent to redraw? How do I fix it so I can set colors of circles outside of paintcomponent..?

Comment: yes, setColor() will cause the paintcomponent to redraw. What you want to do is to do setColor() in the Main constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the help, really helped me figure out what was wrong !

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>        for(int i = 0; i < radius.length; i++)
>        {
>            for (int j = 0; j < radius.length; j++)
>            {
> ```

Most loops where you wish to compare every pairing of two elements together is instead written like this:

> ```
>        for(int i = 0; i < radius.length; i++)
>        {
>            for (int j = i; j < radius.length; j++)
>            {
> ```

(Note the `j = i` in the second loop.)

This also lets you remove the `i != j` test. :)

**EDIT**: Oops; `j = i` means you still need to `i != j` test -- if you used `j = i+1` then you can remove the `i != j` test. Sigh. :)

Comment: Hmm, yes that's true and thank you, but for some reason my i variable is getting reset to 0 and it is rewalking my code, again. So it draws wrong...

Comment: Oh really? Then throw in a handful of `System.out.println("i " + i);` in both loops and see if you can't catch it in the act.

Comment: i 1ST for 0
i 2ND 0
i 2ND 0
i 2ND 0
i 1ST for 1
i 2ND 1
i 2ND 1
i 1ST for 2
i 2ND 2
i 1ST for 0
i 2ND 0
i 2ND 0
i 2ND 0
i 1ST for 1
i 2ND 1
i 2ND 1
i 1ST for 2
i 2ND 2