# why is my code executing paintComponent(Graphics page) twice?

Tags: java, swing, components, drawing, paint

This is getting on my nerves and it probably something silly on my part but I can't figure out why my paintComponent is being called twice, if you run my code it outputs REPEAT? REPEAT? twice, I don't want it to do that.. So why does it do it and how can I fix it?

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends JPanel {


    public Main()
    {      
     /*code here*/
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
    {
     clear(page);

        /*code here*/

        System.out.println("REpEAT?"); 

    }

    protected void clear(Graphics page) {
        super.paintComponent(page);
      }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Circles");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Main());
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }



}
```

Comment: i run your code and paintComponent runs only one time. It prints REpEAT? only one time.

Comment: Really? Is it something wrong with my java installation or something? JavaSE-1.6.0_22 in eclipse and netbeans, its causing REpEAT? twice

Comment: @novar: Yes. I'm also using JRE6 and eclipse. It goes well on my machine.

Comment: Hmm, any idea why a machine would run it twice?

Comment: How complex is your commented out code?  The source of the problem was probably in that code.

Comment: No it isn't, I ran it with the above block on my machine and its outputted repeat twice, I am about to test it on my laptop in a few minutes, ill update if it repeats once (which it should do then)

Comment: Could you check Clip of your Graphics instance?

Comment: ... It just repeated twice on my laptop now, >.< I'm using 64bit java as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It printed out twice for me too.

However, I don't think it is cause for concern. Swing decides when things need to be repainted. For example, if you resize a window or minimise/maximise, Swing will repaint. It might be dependent on the OS/hardware you are running on.

You should write your code so that it is robust enough to handle multiple calls to `repaint`.

Please see this SO question too: [paintComponent is executing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800885/paintcomponent-is-executing-twice)

Comment: Yea ^ that was my previous question, hmm. Alright thanks, I was just wondering why swing decided to repaint..